# C# 6.0 String Interpolation Highlighting

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

Text highlighting for string interpolation is missing for C# 6 syntax

StackOverflow highlighting:

[image: Stackoverflow]

Visual Studio 2015 highlighting:

[image: Visual Studio]

i.e. if the string is prepended with a `$` then `{something }` should be highlighted as normal C# code, not as string literal.

I'll delete if this was reported before; I didn't see anything after a quick search.

I also don't know if this should be tagged bug, or feature-request.

Comment: Make a bug-report to prettify. Good luck, you'll need it, considering the applicable trade-offs.

Comment: fair enough; https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues/420

Comment: Given they don't highlight several C# keywords as such I wouldn't hold my breath :-\